# AngularJS - Custom Directive : Select Control - Filters

Tags: angularjs

**I saw a jsfiddle example for a custom select control directive:**   [http://jsfiddle.net/marco_m_alves/rjbMj/]

```
    myApp.directive('nameValueSelect', function() {
    return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        entry: "=",
        field: "@",
        options: "=",
        onInputChange: "&"
    },
    controller: function($scope) {

        $scope.onChange = function() {
            console.log("selected changed");
            $scope.entry.type = $scope.option.value;
            $scope.onInputChange();
        };

        var getItemForValue = function(value) {
            var item = null;
            $scope.options.forEach(function(_option) {
                if (_option.value == value) {
                    item = _option;
                }
            });
            return item;
        };

        $scope.$watch("entry", function() {
            console.log("entry changed");
            $scope.option = getItemForValue($scope.entry[$scope.field]);
        }, true);

    },
    template: '<select ng-model="option" ng-options="o.name for o in options" ng-change="onChange()">'

};});
```

**And the respective HTML:**

```
  <name-value-select entry="entry" field="type" options="types" on-input-change="onInputChange()"></name-value-select>
```

**My question though is:**

What if I have one or more filters, how would I work them into this directive? I tried various ways to modify the ng-options in the directive to include a filter, all to no avail. Any ideas?

**Here are the two filters I would like to implement:**

| filterByType: 'Front' | orderBy:'name'"

Naturally, I do not want them hard coded into the directive.

**Clarification:**

I am not looking to filter the select value's by their name, per se, rather I am looking to show select values (1) only if they have a "filterByType" attribute value of 'Front' and then (2) filter them alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Add the filters to the expression in the options attribute (in the HTML):

http://plnkr.co/edit/o51eqq6XjIfAjvdtrz96?p=preview

Comment: Hey thanks but you are filtering by select value, whereas in my case, the select values have an attribute called Type. In your example let's say 'Authorized' has  an authorizedBy filter = 'Staff' and 'Not Authorized' had a filter = 'Management', and I did not want to filter by select value, but only show me those select values where authorizedBy: 'Management', and then orderBy: name. I am not looking to filter by the name value itself.

Comment: Gotcha.  I updated the example, take another look.  You can use the built-in 'filter' and 'orderBy' filters for this, although the syntax is somewhat non-obvious.

Comment: Re-ran your plnkr and it does indeed work. I got alot of red script when I emulated it. Then went back to yours and you got alot of red script too. Starting with: Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Comment: Yea, now I see that too.  I'm not sure exactly what is going on, but moving the filter logic to a watcher in the controller solves the problem.  See the updated plunker.  Not very elegant, maybe somebody else has a better solution.